# javascript, taking the value of a variable out of a function in the context of fetch

Tags: javascript

I simplified the code, it would have been too long; I have three functions; the first contains the value, an array called multi, to be brought into the third; the second is only an intermediary

how do i bring multi into the third function?

```
function updateScegliFilm(film) {
  var url1 = "https://api.themovie.org/search/movie?api_key=" + key + "&query=" + film;
  var multi = [];
  fetch(url1)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var idFilmElenco = json['id'];
      var titleFilm = json['title'];
      output = new Array(idFilmElenco, titleFilm);
      multi.push(output);
      return multi;
    });
}

function gestioneElenco(output) {
  output.forEach(film => {
    tendina(film);
  });
}

function tendina(film, multi) {
  updateScegliFilm(film, multi);
  alert(multi);
}
```

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: Unrelated, but `gestioneElenco` is just `output.forEach(tendina)`

Comment: I have read some of the articles you have recommended to me; from my point of view the subject is very complicated; if someone showed me how to handle asynchronous functions on my code it would be ideal

Comment: The dupe does, and there are many, many tutorials available. What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I change the code so: function tendina(film, multi) {

  
    updateScegliFilm(film, multi)

    
    .then(multi=> {

        alert(multi);

    }); and thi is the result: Uncaught ReferenceError: multi is not defined